# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019'

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, pdf

I'm dealing with this error I don't know what's the problem I have already added the font Arial and I've also tried to use the function Unicode() but nothing the same error appears

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 59: ordinal not in range(256)

p.s: I'm using mac os

and this is the code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from fpdf import FPDF
from PyPDF2 import *
from time import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#function to convert minutes to date string 
def Minutes_To_Date(date_minutes):     
    if date_minutes>0:
        Secondes = int(date_minutes*60)
    else : 
        Secondes = 0
    series_format=strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime(Secondes))    
    return series_format

#function to make the data frame into a table in pdf 
def output_df_to_pdf(pdf,df):
    table_cell_width = 25 # set the height of the cell and the width
    table_cell_height = 6
    pdf.add_font("Arial", "", "arial.ttf", uni=True)
    pdf.set_font("Arial", "B", 8)
    cols = df.columns
    #type the first row (name of columns)
    for col in cols: 
        pdf.cell(table_cell_width, table_cell_height, col, align = 'C', border = 1)
    pdf.ln(table_cell_height)
    pdf.set_font("Arial", "", 10)
    #type the rows
    for row in df.itertuples():
        for col in cols :
            value = str(getattr(row,col))
            pdf.cell(table_cell_width, table_cell_height, value, align = "C", border=1)
        pdf.ln(table_cell_height) 
        

#the path of our data 
path = r"/Users/mac/Desktop/data_test.xlsx"

#load the data into data frame 
df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Feuil1')

#add the hours columns to the dataframe 
df["heure"] = (df["Date dernier envoi"].dt.hour)
 
#add the "delai de validation " columns to dataframe 
df["Délai de validation"] = (df["Date action"] - df["Date dernier envoi"])/np.timedelta64(1, 'm') #calculate period in minutes

#create 2 pivot table one to be seen and the other to make graphs 
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values="Délai de validation", index="heure", columns="Nom Service", aggfunc = "mean" , margins=True)
df_pivot_seen = pd.pivot_table(df, values="Délai de validation", index="heure", columns="Nom Service", aggfunc = "mean")
date_minutes_1 = list(df_pivot_seen["AMPE"]) #convert the data frame column to list 
date_minutes_2 = list(df_pivot_seen["AMPI"]) 

#convert the number of minutes to string in form of date 
for i in range(len(date_minutes_1)):
    date_minutes_1[i] = Minutes_To_Date(date_minutes_1[i])
    date_minutes_2[i] = Minutes_To_Date(date_minutes_2[i])

#convert to data frame     
df_pivot_seen["AMPE"] = pd.DataFrame(date_minutes_1)  
df_pivot_seen["AMPI"] = pd.DataFrame(date_minutes_2)

#create a diagram
df_pivot.plot()
plt.savefig("chart.png")


#create fpdf object with default values page:A4 and mesure will be in millimeters
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_font("Arial", "", "arial.ttf", uni=True)
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial","B", 16)

pdf.cell(40,10,"Rapport d’activité Import/Export de la semaine S52")
pdf.ln(20)
pdf.image("chart.png")
pdf.ln(20)
output_df_to_pdf(pdf, df_pivot_seen)

pdf.output("/Users/mac/Desktop/report.pdf", "F")

print(df_pivot_seen)



UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/yv/yjnc8p5j64s70dv3dfh9td600000gn/T/ipykernel_76346/884241888.py in <module>
     83 
     84 
---> 85 pdf.output("/Users/mac/Desktop/report.pdf")
     86 
     87 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py in output(self, name, dest)
   1063         #Finish document if necessary
   1064         if(self.state<3):
-> 1065             self.close()
   1066         dest=dest.upper()
   1067         if(dest==''):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py in close(self)
    244         self._endpage()
    245         #close document
--> 246         self._enddoc()
    247 
    248     def add_page(self, orientation=''):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py in _enddoc(self)
   1634     def _enddoc(self):
   1635         self._putheader()
-> 1636         self._putpages()
   1637         self._putresources()
   1638         #Info

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py in _putpages(self)
   1168             if self.compress:
   1169                 # manage binary data as latin1 until PEP461 or similar is implemented
-> 1170                 p = self.pages[n].encode("latin1") if PY3K else self.pages[n]
   1171                 p = zlib.compress(p)
   1172             else:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 59: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Comment: Could you perhaps include the full traceback? Without it it's hard to know which line of code the error is about.

Comment: ofc i will add it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the font. The original font (Arial only allowed latin-1.